# Serial monitor using TKinter python not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

```
import self
import serial
import time
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import struct
import copy
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTk, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Frame
import pandas as pd


class serialPlot:
    def __init__(self, serialPort='COM12', serialBaud=9600, plotLength=100, dataNumBytes=2, numPlots=1):
        self.port = serialPort
        self.baud = serialBaud
        self.plotMaxLength = plotLength
        self.dataNumBytes = dataNumBytes
        self.numPlots = numPlots
        self.rawData = bytearray(numPlots * dataNumBytes)
        self.dataType = None
        if dataNumBytes == 2:
            self.dataType = 'h'  # 2 byte integer
        elif dataNumBytes == 4:
            self.dataType = 'f'  # 4 byte float
        self.data = []
        for me in range(numPlots):  # give an array for each type of data and store them in a list
            self.data.append(collections.deque([0] * plotLength, maxlen=plotLength))
        self.isRun = True
        self.isReceiving = False
        self.thread = None
        self.plotTimer = 0
        self.previousTimer = 0
        # self.csvData = []

        print('Trying to connect to: ' + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        try:
            self.serialConnection = serial.Serial(serialPort, serialBaud, timeout=4)
            print('Connected to ' + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')
        except:
            print("Failed to connect wif " + str(serialPort) + ' at ' + str(serialBaud) + ' BAUD.')

    def readSerialStart(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.backgroundThread)
            self.thread.start()
            # Block till we start receiving values
            while not self.isReceiving:
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def getSerialData(self, frame, lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText):
        currentTimer = time.clock()
        self.plotTimer = int((currentTimer - self.previousTimer) * 1000)  # teh first reading will be erroneous
        self.previousTimer = currentTimer
        timeText.set_text('Plot Interval = ' + str(self.plotTimer) + 'ms')
        privateData = copy.deepcopy(
            self.rawData[:])  # so dat teh 3 values in our plots will be synchronized to teh same sample time
        for me in range(self.numPlots):
            data = privateData[(me * self.dataNumBytes):(self.dataNumBytes + me * self.dataNumBytes)]
            value, = struct.unpack(self.dataType, data)
            self.data[me].append(value)  # we get teh latest data point and append it to our array
            lines[me].set_data(range(self.plotMaxLength), self.data[me])
            lineValueText[me].set_text('[' + lineLabel[me] + '] = ' + str(value))
        # self.csvData.append([self.data[0][-1], self.data[1][-1], self.data[2][-1]])

    def backgroundThread(self):  # retrieve data
        time.sleep(1.0)  # give some buffer time for retrieving data
        self.serialConnection.reset_input_buffer()
        while self.isRun:
            self.serialConnection.readinto(self.rawData)
            self.isReceiving = True
            # print(self.rawData)

    def sendSerialData(self, data):
        self.serialConnection.write(data.encode('utf-8'))

    def close(self):
        self.isRun = False
        self.thread.join()
        self.serialConnection.close()
        print('Disconnected...')
        # df = pd.DataFrame(self.csvData)
        # df.to_csv('/home/rikisenia/Desktop/data.csv')


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, figure, master, SerialReference):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entry = None
        self.setPoint = None
        self.master = master  # a reference to teh master window
        self.serialReference = SerialReference  # keep a reference to our serial connection so dat we can use it for bi-directional communicate from this class
        self.initWindow(figure)  # initialize teh window wif our settings

    def initWindow(self, figure):
        self.master.title("Real Time Plot")
        canvas = FigureCanvasTk(figure, master=self.master)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.master)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # create out widgets in teh master frame
        lbl1 = Tk.Label(self.master, text="Scaling Factor")
        lbl1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.entry = Tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry.insert(0, '1.0')  # (index, string)
        self.entry.pack(padx=5)
        SendButton = Tk.Button(self.master, text='Send', command=self.sendFactorToMCU)
        SendButton.pack(padx=5)

    def sendFactorToMCU(self):
        self.serialReference.sendSerialData(self.entry.get() + '%')  # '%' is our ending marker


def main():
    # portName = 'COM5'
    portName = 'COM12'
    baudRate = 9600
    maxPlotLength = 100  # number of points in x-axis of real time plot
    dataNumBytes = 4  # number of bytes of 1 data point
    numPlots = 3  # number of plots in 1 graph
    s = serialPlot(portName, baudRate, maxPlotLength, dataNumBytes, numPlots)  # initializes all required variables
    s.readSerialStart()  # starts background thread

    # plotting starts below
    pltInterval = 50  # Period at which teh plot animation updates [ms]
    xmin = 0
    xmax = maxPlotLength
    ymin = -1
    ymax = 1
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(float(ymin - (ymax - ymin) / 10), float(ymax + (ymax - ymin) / 10)))
    ax.set_title('Arduino Accelerometer')
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax.set_ylabel("Accelerometer Output")

    # put our plot onto Tkinter's GUI
    root = Tk.Tk()
    app = Window(fig, root, s)

    lineLabel = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    style = ['r-', 'c-', 'b-']  # linestyles for teh different plots
    timeText = ax.text(0.70, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
    lines = []
    lineValueText = []
    for me in range(numPlots):
        lines.append(ax.plot([], [], style[me], label=lineLabel[me])[0])
        lineValueText.append(ax.text(0.70, 0.90 - me * 0.05, '', transform=ax.transAxes))
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, s.getSerialData, fargs=(lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText),
                                   interval=pltInterval)  # fargs has to be a tuple

    # plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    root.mainloop()  # use this instead of plt.show() since we are encapsulating everything in Tkinter

    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> Basically I want to plot a graph from Arduino serial data also send data back to Arduino using a serial monitor to control the motor rpm.

**I found this code from https://thepoorengineer.com/en/python-gui/
after making some changes the connection is created with serial port but the Tkinter shows not and graph please help me to make this work**

[here the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVJgm.png)

Comment: Need help if any one can !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever exit readSerialStart()? Can you print whatever is coming back from the serial port?

Comment: Yes, I receive the values by using metaplot function but when I put all code in tkinter library make some graphically view I don’t get it